# Coding Like a Pythonista

Tags: python

I'm a professional web dev who has been learning python in my spare time via a MOOC.  I've really enjoyed it, and was hoping for a few tips on how to write more 'pythonic' code.

I basically want to read in a csv that has a one-to-many relationship between nodeID and categoryName/ID. The input file will read as follows:

```
NODEID   CATID   CATNAME
3        4       Plastic
3        5       Sharks with Lasers
4        7       Widgets
```

I want the resulting output to be:

```
NODEID   CATNAME
3        Plastic, Sharks with Lasers
4        Widgets
```

This is how I did it, but I know it's not the most efficient way:

```
import csv  # import the csv module
import sys  # import the sys module
from collections import defaultdict

inputFile = open('term_data.csv', 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
    nodeDict = defaultdict(dict)
    for row in reader:
        colnum = 0
        # nodeDict[nodeid][catid] = catname
        nodeDict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
finally:
    inputFile.close()

f = open('terms.txt', 'w')
for node, nodeVals in nodeDict.items():
    f.write(node + ';')
    #sys.stdout.write(node + ';')
    itera = 0
    for cat, name in nodeVals.items():
        f.write(name)
        itera += 1
        if (itera == len(nodeVals.items())): 
            f.write(';' + '\n')
        else: 
            f.write(',')
```

Any help or criticism would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question may be a better fit for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as bernie said, questions of the type: "It works, but what is a better way" are best asked [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But if you want to know a good way to approach this and problems like it, I would suggest the module [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Just to tease the `pandas` solution: it's basically `df.groupby("NODEID")["CATNAME"].apply(', '.join)`, with a `read_csv` at the start and a `to_csv` at the end, and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it as:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

nodeDict = defaultdict(list)

with open('term_data.csv', 'rb') as inputFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
    next(reader, None)  # Skip header line in file.
    for row in reader:
        nodeDict[row[0].append(row[2])

with open('terms.txt', 'wb') as outputFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
    writer.writerow(['NODEID', 'CATNAME'])
    for node, names in nodeDict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([node] + names)
```

This writes the names as separate columns. If you need them to be in one column, join them separately first, and the `csv.writer()` will quote them to indicate they are one column:

```
    for node, names in nodeDict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([node, ','.join(names)])
```

1. Use `with` to manage file lifetimes; they will be closed automatically this way, whatever else happens in the code.
2. Use `csv` to write the output too, it's CSV data still.
3. You are only writing out the node ids and category names, so that is all you need to collect from the input.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! And apologies for posting this question in the wrong forum.

Comment: No need to apologise, Brandon. We're glad you got an answer. Feel free to accept (click checkmark).